# try and catch block in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, try-catch

I have a laravel project
I tried to handle the error exception so that after catch it redirects to the route
output gave me 500 server error but not the exception message along and neither does it redirects.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    
    return view('showForm');
})->name("start");


Route::post('/upload', function (Request $request) {
    try {
        //code...
        if($request->file("thing")=="") {
            // return back()->withInput();
            return redirect()->route('start')->with('message', 'Insert Data!');
        } else {
            $name=$request->file("thing")->getClientOriginalName();
            $book=DB::table('books')->where('Title',$name)->count();
            if($book>0) {
                return redirect()->route('start')->with('message', 'Document already exists!');
            } else {
                Storage::disk("google")->putFileAs("",$request->file("thing"),$name);
                $url=Storage::disk('google')->url($name);
                $details=Storage::disk("google")->getMetadata($name);
                $path=$details['path'];
                DB::insert('insert into books (Title, Url, FileId) values (?,?,?)', [$name,$url,$path]);
                return redirect()->route('start')->with('message', 'Successfully uploaded document, you have recieved token!');
            }
        }
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        //throw $th;
        return redirect()->route('start')->with('message', $th);
    }
    
})->name("upload");
```

I have this web.php in routes folder which takes input from showForm.blade.php
I want that whatever the error comes it routes back and display that in showForm.blade.php

EDIT
Log:

```
[2021-06-09 19:36:17] local.ERROR: cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 150008 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token {"exception":"[object] (GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ConnectException(code: 0): cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 150008 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Handler\\CurlFactory.php:213)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Handler\\CurlFactory.php(161): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\EasyHandle), Array)
#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Handler\\CurlFactory.php(113): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlFactory))
#2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Handler\\CurlHandler.php(47): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlFactory::finish(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlFactory))
#3 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Handler\\Proxy.php(28): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlHandler->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)
#4 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Handler\\Proxy.php(48): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)
#5 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\PrepareBodyMiddleware.php(64): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)
#6 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Middleware.php(31): GuzzleHttp\\PrepareBodyMiddleware->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)
#7 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\RedirectMiddleware.php(71): GuzzleHttp\\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)
#8 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Middleware.php(61): GuzzleHttp\\RedirectMiddleware->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)
#9 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\HandlerStack.php(75): GuzzleHttp\\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)
#10 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Client.php(331): GuzzleHttp\\HandlerStack->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)
#11 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Client.php(107): GuzzleHttp\\Client->transfer(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)
#12 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Client.php(123): GuzzleHttp\\Client->sendAsync(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)
#13 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\google\\auth\\src\\HttpHandler\\Guzzle6HttpHandler.php(47): GuzzleHttp\\Client->send(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)
#14 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\google\\auth\\src\\OAuth2.php(526): Google\\Auth\\HttpHandler\\Guzzle6HttpHandler->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request))
#15 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\google\\apiclient\\src\\Client.php(334): Google\\Auth\\OAuth2->fetchAuthToken(Object(Google\\Auth\\HttpHandler\\Guzzle7HttpHandler))
#16 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\google\\apiclient\\src\\Client.php(311): Google\\Client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken('1//048duy2JoXIO...')
#17 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\app\\Providers\\GoogleDriveServiceProvider.php(33): Google\\Client->refreshToken('1//048duy2JoXIO...')
#18 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Filesystem\\FilesystemManager.php(143): App\\Providers\\GoogleDriveServiceProvider->App\\Providers\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array)
#19 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Filesystem\\FilesystemManager.php(123): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\FilesystemManager->callCustomCreator(Array)
#20 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Filesystem\\FilesystemManager.php(101): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\FilesystemManager->resolve('google')
#21 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Filesystem\\FilesystemManager.php(78): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\FilesystemManager->get('google')
#22 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade.php(261): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\FilesystemManager->disk('google')
#23 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\
outes\\web.php(41): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('disk', Array)
#24 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(230): Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteFileRegistrar->{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#25 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(200): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runCallable()
#26 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(695): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#27 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#28 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#29 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#30 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#32 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Session\\Store), Object(Closure))
#36 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#37 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#38 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#39 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#40 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#41 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#42 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(697): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#43 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(672): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#44 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(636): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#45 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(625): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#46 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(166): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#47 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#48 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#49 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#50 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#51 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#52 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#53 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#54 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#55 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#56 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#57 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#58 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\fruitcake\\laravel-cors\\src\\HandleCors.php(38): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#59 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#60 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#61 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#62 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#63 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(141): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#64 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#65 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#66 {main}
"} 
[2021-06-10 15:03:10] production.ERROR: Maximum execution time of 360 seconds exceeded {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError(code: 0): Maximum execution time of 360 seconds exceeded at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Handler\\CurlFactory.php:299)
[stacktrace]
#0 {main}
"} 
[2021-06-10 17:30:46] production.ERROR: Maximum execution time of 360 seconds exceeded {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError(code: 0): Maximum execution time of 360 seconds exceeded at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Handler\\CurlFactory.php:299)
[stacktrace]
#0 {main}
"} 
[2021-06-10 17:38:25] production.ERROR: Maximum execution time of 360 seconds exceeded {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError(code: 0): Maximum execution time of 360 seconds exceeded at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Handler\\CurlFactory.php:299)
[stacktrace]
#0 {main}
"}
```

Comment: check your logs at `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: Maximum execution time of 360 seconds exceeded {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError(code: 0): Maximum execution time of 360 seconds exceeded at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Web_Engineering-1\\laravelproject\\example-app\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Handler\\CurlFactory.php:299)
[stacktrace]  that's what it says but how to catch the error and then redirect back to route with message

Comment: It seems that the exception occurs before reaching your function, follow the stacktrace to find where it occurs in your code.

Comment: Can you please tell how to do that, actually its my first time using laravel so I have no idea

Comment: go the last log of your log file, there is a stacktrace, list of files and line numbers that leads to an exception, follow that stacktrace to find the problem.

Comment: If I share the log, can you tell the solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233631/discussion-between-hafez-divandari-and-sa-ira).

Answer (score 0):

This may be a namespace problem, please also try `Throwable` without the slash before it:

```php
try {
  //...
}
catch (Throwable $th) {
 //...
}
```